# Как  обработать данные из файла С++?

Tags: c++

Добрый день, С праздником  Вас Всех.
Помогите решить следующие вопросы:

1. Как обработать полученные  данные из файла
2. Например как посчитать сумму всех цифр находящихся в файле и записать их в другой файл.

> Вот пример программы, которая просто выполняет чтение из файла и выводит их в диалоговое окно, но не производит с ними никаких операций.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
// 1. За что отвечает эта библиотека?
#include <stdio.h>
// Библиотека отвечающая за совместоность с windows.
#include <windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR * argv[])
{
    //Библиотека windos.h
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    //*fp-Выделение памяти и название файла.
    // fopen - открытие файла, test1.txt название текстового файла файла
    // "r" - режим (файл открывается только для чтения.
    FILE *fp = fopen("test1.txt", "r");

    //Если такового файла нет, то выдает ошибку, но почему то сразу закрывает программу
    if (NULL == fp) 
    {
        printf("Не удалось открыть файл!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    //Обозначаем переменную str, типа char, [24] кол-во символов которые буду прочитаны.
    char str[24] = "";
    //2. Что такое feof? И почему перед ним воскл. знак
    while (!feof(fp)) {
    //3. За что отвечает fgets? 
        fgets(str, 24, fp);
        printf("%s", str);
        printf("n");
    }
    //Закрытие файла.
    fclose(fp);
    // Не знаю за что отвечает эта ф-ия (
    system("pause");
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Так как я новичок, то не могли бы вы указывать при помощи "//" что вы делаете при помощи данной операции. Так же в самой программе есть не понятные для меня ф-ии не могли бы вы их пояснить.  Заранее Всем спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Объяснять ничего не стоит, потому что знания просто на нуле. Берем хорошую книгу по С++ и упорно изучаем.

Comment: Мне завтра к 10 утра нужно это сдать или доздравствует академический отпуск

Comment: Лучше отпуск, чем хреновые специалисты.

Comment: Ты чего такой серьезны то. Я много прошу разве? Если FILE *fp = fopen-это чтение из файла, то как будет запись в файл. Я не думаю что там сильно разные операторы.

Comment: @ek8800, есть такая команда - man. Чем задавать примитивные вопросы и препираться с отвечающим, лучше прочесть man fopen, man feof, man fgets и т.п. Сразу говорю, в конце каждого man есть раздел "SEE ALSO". Крайне рекомендую.

Если Вы работаете в видоуз, то можно читать man-ы в интернете [например здесь](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml)

А вот если **после** этого возникают **конкретные** вопросы, тогда милости просим, задавайте.

Comment: @avp, какой man? Тут человек в винде не может разобраться, а Вы "ман"...

Comment: А по манам IMHO проще, чем в винде. Ну и сразу к posix ближе.

Comment: Конеч проще.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- feof - проверка на конец фалйа, знак восклицания это логический NOT
- fgets - если не ошибаюсь возвращает данные из файла
- system - привожу описание с какого-то портала

> Функция system передает заданную строку string к интерпретатору команд и обрабатывает эту строку как команду MS DOS. Функция system ссылается на переменные окружения COMSPEC и PATH, чтобы расположить файл COMMAND.COM, который используется при выполнении команды string.

Comment: 1. fgets - не просто возращает данные, а читает стороку Си из файла и записывает в указанный буфер, но не более числа символов, указанных во втором аргументе. Символ конца строки тоже записывается.
2. system принимает Си-строку как аргумент и выполняет ее в стандартном интерпретаторе системы. В DOS - это командная строка DOS, в никсах - командный интерпретатор пользователя, от чьего лица запускается программа.